# CiviCRM, Ubercart, and donations through the shopping cart

Tags: civicontribute, ubercart

I know that [UC CiviCRM](https://www.drupal.org/project/uc_civicrm) creates a "purchases" tab in the CiviCRM contact view that links purchases made through an Ubercart store. Is it possible to set the Financial Type per product in the Ubercart store? For example, rather than requiring a shopping cart checkout and then a completely separate donation process, it makes sense from a usability standpoint to allow a supporter to add a donation to an Ubercart checkout process (using a [UC Variable Price](https://www.drupal.org/project/uc_varprice) product, for example). It would be nice to be able to do this and have the donation push into CiviCRM automatically, but I have a feeling it is not so easy. Am I right, and if so, what would be the best way to implement this?

Comment: If you haven't it may be worth asking on the UC CiviCRM module issues page too as there will be other eyes on that maybe

Comment: Cross-posted: https://www.drupal.org/node/2482685

Answer (score 1):

we have found that using CiviEntities opens the door for using Rules directly to control what gets pushed in to CiviCRM and how (in our case with Commerce not Ubercart). I can't really flesh out more on this as Eileen did the work  and she is probably en route back from the Sprint in Denver. Perhaps the above is enough to give you something to look in to if no one else comes back with a more succinct solution.

Comment: Thanks -- I will need to do some more exploring with CiviEntities and see if it can help with my case. And maybe explore more of Commerce, too, although my impression was it's overkill for the tiny stores some of the groups we work with have.

Comment: Did you progress this 'exploring' further? Just inherited a D7 ubercart site that has no integration happening with civi

Comment: No more progress with Ubercart. IIRC that particular site ended up building a Commerce cart and working from this as a base: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7062/does-anyone-have-a-recipe-for-commerce-rules-civicrm-integration

Comment: Fair enough. seems getting uc_civicrm working again hasn't proven too hard so far