# Does anyone have a recipe for Commerce / Rules / CiviCRM integration?

Tags: drupal, civicrm-entity, drupal-rules, commerce

I'm helping a group that has a small Commerce store on the site (Drupal 7, CiviCRM 4.6.9) and I'd love to be able to push data from Commerce purchases back into CiviCRM. I have seen some general talk about CiviCRM Entity and Rules integration being able to do this, but I'm curious if anyone has a recipe that is working for them that they would be willing to post -- including the Rule's event(s), condition(s), and action(s) to do this.

I'm assuming the event should be upon successful checkout in Commerce, but I haven't determined the best way to handle conditions and actions.

[image: Event, Condition, Action]

Ideally I'd love to be able to do the following:

- Push first name, last name, billing address into the CiviCRM contact that is already created (but just contains email address)
- On a product type basis (or if necessary, a line item basis) push a contribution onto this contact record, tagged to the appropriate contribution type. (e.g. we have set up the ability to 'add a donation to your order' in the Commerce shopping cart, so we'd like to be able to split apart the physical product purchase into a 'store purchase' contribution, and push any add-on donation as a 'donation' contribution).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Exported Rules:**

The description of what I'm trying to do is below, and you can [download (and/or pitch in) on the current versions of the Rules below at this GitHub repo](https://github.com/CEDC/civicrm_drupal_commerce_rules).

**Problem Areas:**

- In creating the CiviCRM Contribution record, I haven't been able to figure out how to set the Receive Date. I can't input the token for the date of the order because that is of type Date and the CiviCRM Receive Date field only allows data of type Text. Pointers/ideas welcome as currently it leaves the date off completely in the inserted contribution record.
- Also less than ideal is leaving `Fee amount` and `Net amount` blank...
- This seems not to work unless the purchaser is an administrator so I've got some further digging to do on permissions

---

With a lot of trial and error, I have a start on this. This is a work in progress, so feel free to chip in on remaining items if you have an idea or have thought of a better way.

**Needed Modules:**

- Rules
- Commerce
- [Commerce Donate](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_donate) *(if you want to allow a donation to be added in a shopping cart, so they don't need two checkouts)*
- [CiviCRM Entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_entity)
- [Conditional Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) *(to add some conditional logic to the rule)*

**Working Elements:**

- Add some contact info to the CiviCRM contact
- Add separate contributions to the CiviCRM contact depending on type (store item, donation, shipping fee)

**Instructions:**

Set up Commerce Donate and have a pane on your checkout to allow someone to add a donation to a store order:

[image: Commerce Donate]

Now go to Rules (**Configuration > Workflow > Rules**) and create a new rule. I ended up breaking this into two separate rules but after I discovered the Conditional Rules module I'm pretty sure I could have done it in one.

***First rule:*** Add contact info to CiviCRM on store order

1. Events: `Completing the checkout process`
2. Conditions: I don't think any conditions are needed. I have a few in there from testing currently but I don't think they affect anything.
3. Actions:

   - `Fetch entity by id` with Entity type = "CiviCRM Contact" and Identifier = "commerce-order:owner:civicrm-contact:id"
     [image: Entity type/Identifier]
   - `Fetch entity by id` with Entity type = "User" and Identifier = "site:current-cart-order:uid"
   - `Fetch entity by id` with Entity type = "Commerce Customer profile" and Identifier = "site:current-cart-order:uid"
   - `Set a data value` selecting "civi-contact:first-name" and using the value "[customer:commerce-customer-address:first_name]" *(do likewise for any other information you want to pull from the Commerce profile and insert into the appropriate CiviCRM field)*
     [image: Actions]

***Second rule***: Add contribution info to CiviCRM on store order

1. Events: `Completing the checkout process`
2. Conditions: Same as above; I don't think any conditions are needed. I have a few in there from testing currently but I don't think they affect anything.
3. Actions:

   - `Fetch entity by id` with Entity type = "CiviCRM Contact" and Identifier = "commerce-order:owner:civicrm-contact:id"
     [image: Entity type/Identifier]
   - For each contribution type (e.g. donation, store product, shipping fee) do: `Add a variable` to capture the total amount for that type. (e.g. `donation_total`) and set it to 0 to start.
     [image: Add a variable]
   - After all variables are added, `Add a loop` to the rule's actions
   - Within this loop, `Add a switch` on Data to match against = "line-item:type" (switch functionality is provided by the Conditional Rules module; this is assuming your store products are set up as different types -- e.g. Donations as a donation type)
     [image: Switch]
   - For each contribution type again, within this Switch, add a Case (again provided by Conditional Rules) and select the type of product in the Data value. Select "Fall through" as False.
     [image: Case]
   - Within each of these conditional Cases, add two new actions. The first one is to `Calculate a value` (input value 1 as the respective variable you set up above, e.g. `donation_total`, and input value 2 as `line-item:commerce-total:amount-decimal` and the operator as + for addition). The second action within this case is to `Set a data value` on the `donation_total` variable, using the value you just calculated.
     [image: Case Donation]
   - After all of the Cases have been added to the Switch, add a new root level Conditional for each product type, to make sure the total for that type is greater than zero before creating a Contribution record. To do this, choose `Add conditional` and then within this conditional, choose `Add if` with a "Data comparison" to make sure it isn't empty (or is greater than zero).
   - Within this final If, we can add a new action to `Create a new entity`, selecting `CiviCRM Contribution`. Within here, I've added a number of direct input/hard coded values such as:

     - Financial Type ID = 1 (for donations, adjust as needed for other types such as a custom 'Store purchase' financial type within CiviCRM)
     - Total Amount: use the variable that you created and have updated for this type, e.g. total_donations
     - Contact id: `civi-contact:id`
     - Payment Instrument ID: kind of hackish but I've just entered a hard-coded value for credit card purchase (4)
     - You can add a direct input value in the "Contribution source" field and "note" field if you like

[image: Create new entity]

Comment: This is fantastic!  i ran into the the date convert issue in rules.  There are a couple of approaches off the top of my head: 1) fix field in civicrm-entity (see https://www.drupal.org/node/2314125#comment-9112569) 2) convert in rules - https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_data_transforms (you may want a separate rule using variables to simplify or 3) use the API directly in rules which is a bit of a hack ...

Comment: @Sonicthoughts Just tried a test with your suggestion #2, doing a convert to text on the date, and it inserted a contribution record with this date: "October 22nd, 3474 2:45 PM" !!

Comment: When you are comfortable with it please push to github and let's try to get the community to maintain it.

Comment: I haven't found the time to finish this off, but just updated to note another problem area (permissions).

Comment: have you considered exporting your existing Rules and attaching here so others can try them and improve where necessary?

Comment: @petednz-fuzion, yes I will post it. I was going to try to polish it a little more first but I'll add it here in case anyone else needs a gander at it before I get to it.

Comment: great. will you be adding as an attachment or what? (or am i being blind?)

Comment: @petednz-fuzion I added a link to Github at the top of my answer: https://github.com/CEDC/civicrm_drupal_commerce_rules

Comment: great - thought i had scrolled enough but obviously not - sounds like i should be able to add a couple more links for git bits relating to commerce once i ensure they don't have any ticking components in them

Comment: Laryn - eileen's work is https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/commerce_civicrm_rules
and the bit to prefill stuff (ie linked the memberships and participant records to the contact records) https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/commerce_civicrm_prefill

Comment: goal of above was to take every line item in commerce and create unique contribution records from them with associated membership/events etc

Answer (score 2):

As they say ... there is a module for that:[commerce civicrm](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_civicrm)
You can also use rules if you want to trigger other actions but it sounds like this may cover a lot of what you need.

Comment: When we investigated Commerce CiviCRM a year or so ago, it had a number of hardcoded assumptions (eg which type of address is recorded against a transaction) which led us to not use it; it also doesn't seem to be actively maintained. It may be a good reference/starting point for custom work, but may not suit all use cases well.

Comment: And if I remember correctly the module uses an older version of the API. Not a deal breaker, just something to consider.

Comment: which is why we (eileen) headed down the Rules approach instead of the module - but the client we thought was going to let us get it all packaged nicely as as starter kit for others put the project on hold ;(

Comment: Thanks -- yes, I had seen the module but it looked limited and like it was on the way out. Since I'd seen a lot of talk of using Rules with this I was keen to try that out and see if I could get the custom functionality of different "Financial Types" within a single store order.