# Does CiviCRM have camp or conference housing capabilities?

Tags: civievent, evaluating-civicrm

I am evaluating CiviCRM for a camp and conference center with extensive on-site housing (former college campus). It seems very well-suited except that it seems to be lacking a housing piece. The only information I could find on this was an old forum post that went nowhere: [Does CiviEvent have housing management capabilities?](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=6839.msg30174#msg30174)

Is there anything like this in existence? I found information on using Drupal, Webform Integration, and Ubercart for web-based camp registrations, but a housing component is very important for a large facility like ours.

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A housing component is not available in CiviCRM itself. You could possibly try to use CiviBooking (https://civicrm.org/extensions/civibooking), which deals with resource bookings. Depending on your exact functional requirement that might be sufficient. If you are just concerned about booking rooms it might well do for you.

If not, it will probably be a CiviCRM extension that you either have to develop yourself or find a CiviCRM specialist to develop it for you. This is very possible, we have done some specific stuff for a Dutch Housing Corporation in the past.

Answer (score 2):

FYI you don't need Ubercart any more for camp registrations - CiviCRM plus Drupal Webform integration can do it all.

The simplest way to allocate housing would be by creating a custom field (extending Participants) to specify which house/room the participant will be in. This of course lacks anything "smart" like telling whether a particular room is already booked for a given time. Depending on the complexity of your organization, you could solve that by creating a Drupal View of participants and their room booking, which would let you visually see what's taken so you don't double-book. Or you could try out the [CiviBooking extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civibooking).

Answer (score 1):

It would be a bit of a parallel installation to CiviCRM, but there is a Drupal module called [Rooms](https://www.drupal.org/project/rooms), and it handles rooms and buildings, I think. It might be useful in conjunction with Commerce.

Features (from the project page):

> - Create rooms and assign availability (or on hold states) via a calendar.
> - Manage pricing for rooms using calendars that allow to set pricing for entire seasons or just change it for specific dates.
> - Define optional add-ons for rooms.
> - Charge either per-night or per-person.
> - Handle children discounts.
> - Create bookings and keep customer records.
> - Make rooms available for booking with a availability search functionality and/or calendar - handling both immediate bookings and bookings following owner confirmation.
> - Search by Room Type.
> - Handle multiple owners within a single Drupal installation through fine-grained permissions.
> - Full integration with Commerce to manage payments, a range of different payment gateways, and a host of other e-commerce features.
> - Accept full or partial payments (deposits) using Commerce features.

I am actually working on a project that uses it currently and am playing with [Rules to push rental/reservation payment data from Commerce into CiviCRM](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7062/does-anyone-have-a-recipe-for-commerce-rules-civicrm-integration).