# Integrating CiviCRM events with Drupal Commerce?

Tags: drupal, commerce

I am wondering if anyone has successfully integrated CiviCRM events with Drupal Commerce. I'd like to sell events through commerce to prevent having a two commerce solutions on one site. I am aware of Commerce CiviCRM, but it seems irrelevant for the purpose of selling event registration.

Does anyone have a working model for selling event registration through commerce?

Comment: Have you tried doing it with webform-civicrm integration?

Comment: I haven't tried your module Coleman but I will before proceeding

Comment: Your question is also very similar to this one to the point that I wonder if this should be set as a duplicate  http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7062/does-anyone-have-a-recipe-for-commerce-rules-civicrm-integration

Answer (score 3):

Having spent time working with the CiviCRM Commerce module approach, the route we now recommend is using [CiviCRM Entities](https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_entity) and [Drupal Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules). We don't have a package of such Rules yet as the project that was going to give us the time to do this has been deferred.

Comment: What kind of rules did you intend on implementing? If I were creating these rules, would I want to modify the CiviCRM Event entity or the user's Contact entity?

Comment: Looking at the civicrm schema, it seems what I REALLY need to do is have  Rules generate a new CiviCRM participant entity. Going to work on this and report on my progress...

Comment: Matt - any progress in the last 20 months?

Comment: @MattLongman I would be really interested in this as well.  I'm eager to get my users away from having any access to civicrm and just using CiviCRM Entity for registration and Commerce for the payment flow...but registration, participation, and payment records still need to be kept in CiviCRM.